# Parsing custom identifier with nom

Tags: parsing, rust, nom

I am interested to use **nom** parser combinators to recognize identifiers of this kind:

```
"a"
"a1"
"a_b"
"aA"
"aB_3_1"
```

The first character of the identifier should be an alphabetic lower cased character then any combination of alphanumeric character and underscore (so `[a-zA-Z0-9_]*`) could follow, with the restriction that a double (or more) underscore must not occurred and an underscore must not end the identifier, rejecting those cases:

```
"Aa"
"aB_"
"a__a"
"_a"
```

So far I have come with this solution but unsure about correctness of my approach:

```
pub fn identifier(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    let (i, _) = verify(anychar, |c: &char| c.is_lowercase())(s)?;
    let (j, _) = alphanumeric0(i)?;
    let (k, _) = recognize(opt(many1(preceded(underscore, alphanumeric1))))(j)?;
    Ok((k,s))
}
```

Also I need to wrap around a `recognize` this `identifier` parser when using it, like this:

```
pub fn identifier2(s: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    (recognize(identifier))(s)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the variant I came up with. It's mostly the same as yours; I made the following changes:

- Most importantly, I added `all_consuming`, which ensures that the entire input matches. The bug in your proposed implementation is that "aBa_" would *successfully* match the identifier "aBa" and leave the trailing "_" unparsed (returning it in the input side).
- Rewrote exclusively in terms of parser combinators, rather than using `?` statements.
- Made the underscore matching optional. Nom parsers are greedy in general, so this won't lead to performance degradation.
- Simplified to only 2 clauses, instead of 3. The parser essentially runs "match any lower case character, followed by 0 or more runs of an optional _ followed by 1 more more alphanumerics".
- Changed `many1` to `many0_count`, simply because the latter doesn't allocate a vector.
- Made the function generic over the error type, allowing users of the function to use any error type they wish.

```rust
pub fn identifier<'a, E: ParseError<&'a str>>(s: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, &'a str, E> {
    recognize(all_consuming(pair(
        verify(anychar, |&c| c.is_lowercase()),
        many0_count(preceded(opt(char('_')), alphanumeric1)),
    )))(s)
}
```

This function as written passes all test cases you provided. If you specifically *don't* want the `all_consuming`, perhaps because this is being used as part of a larger set of parsers, you'll have to manually check that the recognized identifier doesn't end in a `_` character.

Comment: Thanks @Lucretiel, you solve exactly what I wanted (no vector allocation, all_consuming behavior, removal of lets), thank you!